# Java pre and post incrementing

Tags: java, loops, post-increment, pre-increment

I am having trouble understanding the following code block.

```
   int count = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
       count += (count++);
       System.out.println("count = " + count);
       System.out.println("i = " + i);
   }
```

My understanding is that the loop runs three times preforming the following

```
count = count + count
count = 1 + count
```

This translates to the following as count initially is 0:

```
count = 0 + 0
count = 1 + 0 = 1
count = 1 + 1 = 2
count = 1 + 2 = 3
count = 3 + 3 = 6
count = 6 + 1 = 7
```

The output is below, and count is printed as 0.

```
    count = 0
    i = 0
    count = 0
    i = 1
    count = 0
    i = 2
```

Could someone explain this to me?
Thanks

Comment: I understand that for homework/code understanding issues, this question makes sense. But no one should ever write a confusing line like `count += (count++);` in a production system.

Comment: @MikeRyan Totally agreed. If someone asked me what that line did, and I were in a snarky mood, I'd reply "it gets your merge proposal rejected."

Comment: Is there a rule in FindBugs (or similar open source tools) which would catch this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
count += (count++);
```

is equivalent to

```
in tmp = count;      // right hand side of +=
count = count + 1;   // the count++
count = tmp + tmp;   // executing count += tmp
```

As you can see the `count = count + 1` has no effect, since the value of `count` is overwritten in the last line, and if `count` is initially 0, then the result will obviously be `count = 0 + 0` :-)

Comment: but tmp = 1 here? should it be int tmp = count + 0 ?

Comment: I think your first line should be `int tmp = count + count;`

Comment: I like this example best, disregarding the error in tmp = count + 1.

Answer (score 7):

The confusing part is this line --

```
count+ = (count++);
```

This effectively is doing this --

```
count = count + ( count++ );
```

So, the value of `(count++)` for the equation is 0, the post-increment happens after, but then `count` gets assigned a 0, so the post-increment is thrown away.

This happens 3 times.